# how can i make pandas dataframe objects using for loop in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop

I want to create multiple pandas data frames df1,df2,df3,... from multiple files file1.xlsx, file2.xlsx ... using for loop

```
filenames = {'file1.xlsx','file2.xlsx','file3.xlsx','file4.xlsx','file5.xlsx'}

for i in range(len(filenames)):
    df+str(i) = pd.read.excel(filenames[i])
```

and get the syntax error 'can't assign to operator' how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `locals` but not recommend

```
filenames = {'file1.xlsx','file2.xlsx','file3.xlsx','file4.xlsx','file5.xlsx'}
variables = locals()
for i in range(len(filenames)):
   variables["df{0}".format(i)]  = pd.read.excel(filenames[i])
```

We usually save it into `dict`

```
filenames = {'file1.xlsx','file2.xlsx','file3.xlsx','file4.xlsx','file5.xlsx'}
d={'df'+str(i) :  pd.read.excel(filenames[i]) for i in range(len(filenames))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this? Use `exec` to assign the value to the variable?

```py
filenames = ['file1.xlsx','file2.xlsx','file3.xlsx','file4.xlsx','file5.xlsx']

for fname in filenames:
    dfname = fname.split('.')[0]
    df = pd.read_excel(fname)
    exec("%s=%s" % (dfname , df))
```